# Why bumptech/glide does not loading images when device has landscape orientation?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-glide

In my app I has page that displays a list of images. I use Glide library to load images.
So, the problem is landscape orientation. If device orientation is portrait - all good, but if landscape - "Permission denial opening provider requires that you obtain access using ACTION_GET_DOCUMENT or related APIs".

I have only one permission in my manifest file:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />`.

This is my Glide code for loading image:

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(uriArrayList.get(position))
    .dontAnimate()
    .into(holder.imageView);
```

I tried to find information about this but couldn't find anything that I really needed.

Adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` was not helpful.